# Como incorporar chaquopy a mi app usando android studio para ejecutar un script de python

Tags: java, python, android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una app en android studio de reconocimiento de imagenes. La parte que entrena el modelo y el procesamiento de imagenes lo hago en python y lo que me gustaria sería añadir este codigo de python a android studio y poder usarlo en mi app.

La app haría una imagen con la camara del movil u obtiene la imagen de la galeria y esta imagen se le pasa al codigo de python. He mirado por internet y hablan mucho de usar chaquopy pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar, todos los videos son de hace años y no encuentro algo reciente, por favor alguien me podría ayudar?